# How to use gremlin vertex value to query an edge property

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

I need to take the value of a vertex and use those individual values to query an edge value and return the edge info.

In the SM node, I have all properties: m1, m2, m3, m4 and v2. I will need v2, to query the id of the v2 node. From there I need to concatenate the properties of m1,m2,m3,m4 and v2 to find the edge or I can find the node with the properties m1,m2, m3, m4 and then find the edge.

[Vertext- Edge drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87uol.png)

Answer (score 1):

Querying an edge by the property of a vertex can be achieved like this:

Added data with below query:

```
g.addV('vertex').
  property(id, 'sm2').
  property('m1', 'm1').
  property('m2', 'm2').
  property('m3', 'm3').
  property('m4', 'm4').
  property('v2', 'v2').
  addV('vertex').
  property(id, 'v2').
  addE('MRM').to(V('sm2')).iterate()
```

Used below query to find an incoming edge based on property.

```
gremlin>  g.V('sm2').as('b').
......1>   values('v2').as('a').
......2>   select('b').
......3>   in().as('output').
......4>   id().
......5>   where(eq('a')).
......6>   select('output')
==>v[v2]
```

However, for concatenating all the properties:
Gremlin does not have very good support for string concatenation like you asked for. Having said that, Gremlin java server should still be able to cater to your requirements provided you also use gremlin java client. You can take a look at `The Lambda Solution` section in https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-java-lambda